# Deploying Angular firebase project

Tags: angular, firebase

I am building a web application with Angular and firebase and I have set up everything and import required module and trying to run ng build --prod command then getting below error.

```
Warning: Entry point '@angular/fire' contains deep imports into 'C:/Users/Hello/eShop/node_modules/firebase/app'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
Warning: Entry point '@angular/fire/auth' contains deep imports into 'C:/Users/Hello/eShop/node_modules/firebase/app'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
Warning: Entry point '@angular/fire/auth-guard' contains deep imports into 'C:/Users/Hello/eShop/node_modules/firebase/app'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
Warning: Entry point '@angular/fire/database' contains deep imports into 'C:/Users/Hello/eShop/node_modules/firebase/database', 'C:/Users/Hello/eShop/node_modules/firebase/app'. This is probably not a problem, but may
cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
Warning: Entry point '@angular/fire/firestore' contains deep imports into 'C:/Users/Hello/eShop/node_modules/firebase/app'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
Warning: Entry point '@angular/fire/functions' contains deep imports into 'C:/Users/Hello/eShop/node_modules/firebase/app'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
Warning: Entry point '@angular/fire/messaging' contains deep imports into 'C:/Users/Hello/eShop/node_modules/firebase/app'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
Warning: Entry point '@angular/fire/performance' contains deep imports into 'C:/Users/Hello/eShop/node_modules/firebase/app'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
Warning: Entry point '@angular/fire/remote-config' contains deep imports into 'C:/Users/Hello/eShop/node_modules/firebase/app'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
Warning: Entry point '@angular/fire/storage' contains deep imports into 'C:/Users/Hello/eShop/node_modules/firebase/storage', 'C:/Users/Hello/eShop/node_modules/firebase/app'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
Warning: Entry point 'angularfire2' contains deep imports into 'C:/Users/Hello/eShop/node_modules/firebase/app', 'C:/Users/Hello/eShop/node_modules/rxjs/Observable'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.



ERROR in node_modules/angularfire2/database/database.module.d.ts:15:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (angularfire2/database) which declares AngularFireDatabaseModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

15 export declare class AngularFireDatabaseModule {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/angularfire2/auth/auth.module.d.ts:15:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (angularfire2/auth) which declares AngularFireAuthModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

15 export declare class AngularFireAuthModule {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

After correction of angularfire2 to @angular/fire  i am getting another error.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/fire/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/angular-fire.js 166:8-19
"export 'subscribeOn' was not found in 'rxjs/operators'
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (C:\Users\Hello\eShop\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:109:11)
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getErrors (C:\Users\Hello\eShop\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:68:16)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (C:\Users\Hello\eShop\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1463:22)
    at C:\Users\Hello\eShop\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1258:10
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\Hello\eShop\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:42:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\Hello\eShop\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.finish (C:\Users\Hello\eShop\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1253:28)
    at C:\Users\Hello\eShop\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:672:17
    at _done (eval at create (C:\Users\Hello\eShop\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\Hello\eShop\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:36:22)
    at C:\Users\Hello\eShop\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1185:12
    at C:\Users\Hello\eShop\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1097:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:76:11)
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

Comment: Does your `package.json` include `angularfire2` as a dependency? It's deprecated, outdated, and should not be used anymore. That package has been moved to `@angular/fire`.

Comment: @Kishan,Yes i correct that now i am getting another error please see above error